# Optimize use of google distance matrix api

Tags: google-api, google-distancematrix-api

I am working on services for app in which I need to show the listing of nearby places along with the driving distance for each place from the current user location .

For places I am using google place api which is hit once for each request but google distance api needs to be hit for all the places in the listing due to which I am getting over usage error from google .

Is there any way by which I can avoid hitting distance matrix api again and again ?

Does it make sense to cache results in database as there will be infinite lat longs to calculate distance from?

Comment: Caching won't make sense but you can try it ;)
Why not look for an alternative without those limits?

Comment: @Karussell can you suggest me some alternate ?

Comment: do a web or stackoverflow search or look into my profile ;)